# Lock Android tablet in Chrome shortcut

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am seeking for a way to lock/restrict a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3, which runs Android 4.4.2, on a Google Chrome screen shortcut.

Comment: There isn't a way to lock a tablet from a webpage.

Comment: Not from, but on. Maybe there is a software that let's me restrict the usability of a tablet to a webpage, withou having the browser's search bar and so on.

Comment: That's called kiosk mode, and its a LOT of work to do

Comment: I've tried a lot of kiosk apps, but none suited me, except for one that javascript doesn't work on.